# Why cant I add store procedure in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have store procedures. I try to add them to the entity framework. I chose update model from database and then selected the store procedure. I can see all my stored procedures and then I chose to add them. I clicked the finish button. Then I looked at the store procedure on my entity frame work and I saw it didn't do anything.  It wasn't added.  Why is this happening?

These are all the procedures I chose.
[image: These are all the procedures I chose.]

At the end of finishing, I can't see my procedures in the list.
[image: At the end of finishing, I can't see my procedures in the list.]

Comment: This question probably won't be answered.  I would recommend adding screenshots and showing the progress of what you tried.  Otherwise it's really just a *I did this and that didn't work* issue that will most likely not solvable.

Comment: O sorry. Now ı add the screenshots. :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. My procedures are under the package. For that reason, I can't import them. İf the procedures are under the package follow these steps:

1. Right click in model.
2. Choose update model from database
3. Un-tick the import selected store procedures
4. Now choose store procedures and finish. It will be done.

Answer (score 0):

A new Visual Studio update has introduced a new bug if you're using EF 6, rather than EF Core.  You can see some details [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Entity-Framework-not-importing-stored-pr/10536374?space=8&q=procedure%20view):

[image]

If when you load stored procedures a message flashes up (too fast to read) and you can't then see them, you could do what I did: exit VS 2022, go into VS 2019 which you have on the same laptop, load the stored procedure, save the model, exit VS 2019 and go back into VS 2022!

But I think I'm going to have to bite the bullet and update to EF Core some time ...